# Python list recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to get a nesting list using python,looking likes

```
[[['a'],'a'],'a']
```

So,I wrote a recursion function to get it.

```
def recursion(x,i):
   x.append(list('spam'))
   x=[x]
   i-=1
   print('i value is %d'%i)
   print(x)
   if i>0:
       print('start new recursion!')
       recursion(x,i)
   print('callback x"s value:',x)
   #return x
```

But ,if I call this function like

```
x=[] 
recursion(x,4)
```

The result of x is

```
[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]
```

I don't understand it,and I found that this function seem had get the right value of x through the stdout,

```
i value is 3
[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
start new recursion!
i value is 2
[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
start new recursion!
i value is 1
[[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
start new recursion!
i value is 0
[[[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']],       ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
callback x"s value: [[[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
callback x"s value: [[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]
callback x"s value: [[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]
callback x"s value: [[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]
```

Please tell me what happen to x and why the function don't return x's value I wanted.Thanks so much,and apologize for my poor english.

#

Thanks for your all attention.The value of x I want to get is

```
[[[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']],       ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]]
```

I'm sorry that I missed it in the first post.

Comment: Your question is not clear, because you don't show what x is when you call `recursion(x, 4)` and you don't specify the expected output for this case

Comment: Do you expect to get `[[[['s'], 'p'], 'a'], 'm']` or: `'[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]`

Comment: Thanks first,it's my wrong that I don't show your what I want to get.In fact,the result I want is '[[[['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']] ,thanks for your attention again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not sure what you want to happen, but if you want to split a string into its characters and put them into nested lists, this function works.

```
def recursion(l,s):
    if s == "":
        return l;
    elif len(l) == 0:
        nL = [s[0]]
        return recursion(nL,s[1:])
    else:
        nL = [l,s[0]]
        return recursion(nL,s[1:])
```

So for example

```
print recursion([],"spam")
```

would output

```
[[[['s'], 'p'], 'a'], 'm']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to happen, but here's what is happening:

```
def recursion(x,i):
   x.append(list('spam'))
   x=[x]
```

Here, x becomes `[['s','p','a','m']]`. But it doesn't change after this. When you call `recursion(x,i)` a few lines later, this does not affect the original value of x.

Maybe if you do `x = recursion(x,i)` instead it will give you what you want, because x will actually be change at the top level.

Comment: Thank you so much,I make me know why it happens.But you must miss something ,I have updated my post for the x value I want.And I try to use your code to settle my problem ,I failed.May I ask for a working codes?Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused by the fact that a Python `string` ("spam" is a string) is in many ways equivalent to a Python `list`. You can index them, get their `len()`, etc. In particular, pretty much anything you do in square brackets works for both `string` and `list` types.

Your first example is of a single-byte string, `[[['a'], 'a'], 'a']` but you don't give us some key details: what was the input that you expected to produce this output?

For example, the input might have been:

```
func('a', 3)
```

Or might have been:

```
func('aaa')
```

Or might have been:

```
func(['a'], 3)   # or ,2)
```

Or might have been:

```
func(['a', 'a', 'a'])
```

Any of those would be a reasonable starting point for a return value of `[[['a'], 'a'], 'a']`.

**Solution**

Because your example function takes a second parameter, `i`, I'm going to assume there is a real need for it. So let's go with the simplest possible case:

```
def func(lst, times):
    """
    Given a list and a multiplier > 0, return a "nested" list with 
    the contents of the original list repeated (nested) that many
    times:

        Input:  [a,b],2
        Output: [[a,b],a,b]
    """
    assert times > 0
    if times == 1:
        return lst[:]
    else:
        result = lst[:]
        result.insert(0, func(lst, times-1))
        return result

    for times in range(1,4):
        print(func(['a', 'b'], times))
```

**Alternate**

Here's a simpler function, that doesn't assume a list:

```
def func(content, times):
    """
    Given content and a multiplier > 0, return a set of nested lists,
    with the requested depth, each containing optionally any further
    nested lists and the given content.

        Input:  'content', 2
        Output: [['content'], 'content']
    """
    assert(times > 0)
    if times == 1:
        result = [content]
    else:
        result = [func(content, times-1)]
        result.append(content)
    return result

for times in range(1,4):
    print(func('a', times))
```